# WPF View not rendering on changing contentControl bound property

Tags: wpf, view, rendering, contentcontrol

I am changing user controls on my main window using a bound property on a content control.

XMAL:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding MainContent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></ContentControl>
```

PROPERTY:

```
private UserControl _mainContent;
public UserControl MainContent
{
  get
  {
    return _mainContent;
  }
  set
  {
    _mainContent = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
MainContent = new TestUserControl();
```

ON PROPERTY CHANGED:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
  if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged()
{
  string propertyName = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name.Substring(4);
  OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
}
```

My Problem is that on one specific test machine (similar to others, nothing unique or strange about it. Windows 7, 4GB Ram etc), when changing the usercontrols using this mechanism, the application hangs.

Looking at my logs, the Change command is received, the new user control is instantiated, the constructor runs. The Main Content Property is set, the OnPropertyChanged event fires

and then nothing. The application hangs and windows says its not responding and closes the app.

The OnLoaded event of the user control never gets fired.

This happens on loading any user control this way on the specific machine.

Ideas, comments are all welcome. Idea how to debug this one are welcome.

**UPDATE:**
As this is a test machine, its not rebooted very often.

Once we rebooted the machine, the problem went away. *I would still like to know why and how to stop this happening again.*

PS. The Target platform is x86 and the problem machine is x64, but on the other window 7 x64 there was no issue. We are using .net framework 4.0

Comment: Which version of the framework are you targeting? What is your build config (x86 / any / x64)? Is the target machine Windows 32 or 64bit? I had some problems recently on one machine (Win 7 64 bit with build for "any cpu") with other strange behaviour and only making a build for x64 helped.

Comment: Try to convert your MainContent Property into a dependency property.
You can bind on dependency properties defined in the code behind of your window in xaml by giving the window a name and using the ElementName syntax like {Binding ElementName=myWindow, Path=MainContent}. Its just a guess. See if that helps.
You can also add in your binding PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, and see if the output returns anything useful.
Otherwise it would guess a its a problem with the mashine, not with the code.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this once before, it was caused by me using:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged()
{
  string propertyName = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name.Substring(4);
  OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
}
```

Your properties get inlined in release mode (and perhaps during your compile) so the property name was not correctly identified by the stack search...

Comment: Using `StackTrace` like this can be dangerous because of method inlining when code is optimized. Although this particular implementation may work because the method is `virtual` and therefore won't be inlined.